# How to get the object of element on which dragged element is dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get the element on which dragged element is dropped using jquery i tried using droppable but the object is returning 0 for both left and top. Here is the code can anyone help?

```
$(".cards_images").droppable({
            drop:function(event,ui){
                var pos = $(this).position()
                alert(pos.top)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Your code should work. `$(this)` _is_ the droppable. I just [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/88dTS/1/) and get non-zero position. Maybe something else is wrong. Can you post more code?

Comment: @andyb - You are right, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` *is* the droppable and there is nothing wrong with your code, apart from a few missing `;` :-) I just [**tested**](http://jsfiddle.net/88dTS/1/) this and get non-zero position. Do you have a missing library or other JavaScript error being reported?

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
$(".cards_images").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.draggable.position();
        alert(pos.top);
    }
})
```